# TV probably doesn't have HDMI CEC - Unable to control OSMC on Pi 2 thru TV remote. Help

Tags: hdmi, remote

My [TV](http://www.snapdeal.com/product/micromax-50b5000fhd-50-inches-full/1405132060#bcrumbSearch:micromax%20tv) - An Indian OEM probably doesn't have HDMI CEC and I am unable to control the Pi 2 running OSMC thru my TV's remote.

This is quite a pain as you'd imagine, and I had a few questions

1. IS this a TV thing? Is there any way to augment the TV feature set if this is indeed a TV Thing?
2. Is this an OSMC thing if not a TV Thing? What can i do to fix this?
3. Can I use other Universal remotes in order to get this to work? Would that help?
4. Finally, any tips on configuring an IR receiver or installing OpenElec and using something like Yatze?

Comment: You need to check if the TV has a CEC feature. Panasonic calls its VieraLink for example. I had to connect the Pi, then on the TV use link devices via vieralink menu and then CEC worked. Any remote that supported it. So my sattelite could control the XBMC on the Pi or my TV remote control the Pi with the TV control. Not all buttons work for me though but play, stop, up down left right and back.

Answer (score 2):

In my Philips TV I had to enable CEC in the menu (it's not called CEC, but something like "smart link" or something.
So try these things:

1. Try the options menu to find something that could be CEC and enable it
2. Verify if you have the CEC packages installed on the Pi
3. Verify if it's enabled in Kodi
4. (optional) forget CEC and download a remote like Yatse or Kore for android (apple appstore has a few unofficial Kodi remotes aswell)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [FLIRC remote](http://www.modmypi.com/blog/how-to-raspberry-pi-media-centre-with-flirc-remote-set-up) set up if you don't have HDMI-CEC. Insert the FLIRC hardware into a Pi2 USB port, then configure FLIRC to respond to your TV's remote control (or buy a separate remote control (such as an Apple Remote) if no suitable buttons are available on your TV remote control).

Note that unfortunately HDMI-CEC is called [different things](http://www.howtogeek.com/207186/how-to-enable-hdmi-cec-on-your-tv-and-why-you-should/) by all major TV makers.